# How to get Credit Card Information using CyberSource?

Tags: c#, credit-card

In my project I use Cybersource (a credit card processing service). I need a way to get the user card information (especially credit card number), considering that in database I store only the orderID and the transactionCode for a payment. Is there a method in CyberSource that return this info?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd sincerely hope not. Why do you want it?

Comment: I need to display the last 4 numbers from credit card number.

Comment: That's usually done by storing a masked version of the number when you first took the payment.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to get the full card number back. This is because the payment service provider will be PCI-DSS compliant. As part of that compliancy they must ensure that any system that card details are passed to is also PCI compliant.

If you need to store the last four digits, then you should do so at the point of capture. Obviously, take great care that you are only storing the last four digits. PCI rules state you can store (at most) the first six and last four digits in plain text.

Comment: I know that I can store only 4 digits, but after the transaction is complete, can I get this numbers? (using only OrderID an TransactionCode)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to add:

You can retrieve the last four digits of the card through the business center by searching for the subscription. I haven't seen a way to get the masked data through the API.

This isn't really what you were asking, but it may possible to get the full card information, if you submit a request to Cybersource and pay for their legal dept to handle it (I was quoted roughly $500). I inquired about this when contemplating a change to a different service.